# How to solve "Expected to return a value in arrow function" error in eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am using eslint and getting this error.

> Expected to return a value in arrow function

The error is showing on the third line of the code.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let initialPrices = {};

    data.map(({ category, options }) => {
      initialPrices = {
        ...initialPrices,
        [category]: options[0].price,
      };
    });

    setSelectedPrice(initialPrices);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Don't use `map` for side effects. Use the output of `map` or use `forEach` or a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function is intended to be used when you want to apply some function over every element of the calling array. I think here it's better to use a `forEach`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let initialPrices = {};

    data.forEach(({ category, options }) => {
      initialPrices = {
        ...initialPrices,
        [category]: options[0].price,
      };
    });

    setSelectedPrice(initialPrices);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `map` function must return a value. If you want to create a new object based on an array you should use the `reduce` function instead.

```
const reducer = (accumulator, { category, options }) => (
{...accumulator, [category]:options[0].price}
)
const modifiedData = data.reduce(reducer)
```

More information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` function should return something. Here it's not the case so the error happens. Maybe a reduce function will be more appropriate than map?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your case, is that you want to populate `initialPrices`, and after that to pass it `setSelectedPrice`. The `map` method is not a solution, for you in this case, because this method returns an array.
A safe bet in your case would a `for in loop`, a `forEach`, or a `reduce` function.

```
const data = [
  {

    category: "ball",
    options: [
      {
        price: "120.45"
      }
    ]
  },
  {

    category: "t-shirt",
    options: [
      {
        price: "12.45"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The forEach example:

```
let initialPrices = {};

// category and options are destructured from the first parameter of the method
data.forEach(({ category, options}) => {
  initialPrices[category] = options[0].price;
});

// in this process I'm using the Clojure concept to add dynamically the properties

setSelectedPrice(initialPrices);
```

The reduce example:

```
const initialPrices = Object.values(data).reduce((accumulatorObj, { category, options}) => {
        accumulatorObj[category] = options[0].price
  return accumulatorObj;
}, {});
setSelectedPrice(initialPrices);
```